# resize all images in the page after resizing the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to resize the images in my page after resizing the browser. I could manage but I just want to know if there is a better way to resize all images with different width (square, rectangular,..) without the need to call the `displayWindowSize();` for every image and setting different value `3,5` . The value is the relation between the tpReport width and the image width.

What is the best way to resize all images with different width in the page?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
         $(window).resize(function() {
         if(this.resizeTO) clearTimeout(this.resizeTO);
             this.resizeTO = setTimeout(function() {
               $(this).trigger('windowResize');
             }, 200); 
         });

         $(window).on('windowResize', function() {
            console.log($(window).width()); 
             var tpReportWidth = $("#tpReport").width();

             //var squareWidth = $("#square").width();
             displayWindowSize(5, tpReportWidth,"#square");

             //var rectangularWidth = $("#rectangular").width();
             displayWindowSize(3, tpReportWidth,"#rectangular");

         });

         function displayWindowSize(value, tpReportWidth, selector) {  
           var newIconWidth = Math.round(tpReportWidth/value).toFixed(2);
           console.log('iconWidth after: ' + newIconWidth);
           //$(selector).attr('height',newIconWidth);
          $(selector).attr('width',newIconWidth);
         };         
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <p id="demo"></p>
      <div id="tpReport"  style="float:right;background-color:yellow; display:inline-block; width:45%;">
         <p>Try to resize the browser window to display the windows height and width.</p>
         <span  style="bottom: 60%; left: 41%;clear:both;" >
           <a href="#"> 
            <img id="rectangular" src="rectangular.png" /> 
           </a>
         </span> 

          <span  style="bottom: 10%; left: 41%;float:right;" >
           <a href="#"> 
             <img id="square" src="square.png" /> 
           </a>
         </span> 
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should use `max-width` in CSS & get rid of all of your JS.

Comment: If there are more than a few images, this will make windowing systems that do live updates pretty slow.

Comment: Couldn't you use css media queries to change the displayed image dimensions for different document widths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem can be solved without Javascript.
If your images sizes depend on window width then consider using `vw` units.

```css
#tpReport {
  float: right;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45%;
}

#square {
  width: 9vw
}

#rectangular {
  width: 15vw
}
```

```html
<div id="tpReport" style="">
  <p>Try to resize the browser window to display the windows height and width.</p>
  <span style="bottom: 60%; left: 41%;clear:both;">
           <a href="#"> 
            <img id="rectangular" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5d/Pear_DS.jpg/220px-Pear_DS.jpg" /> 
           </a>
         </span>

  <span style="bottom: 10%; left: 41%;float:right;">
           <a href="#"> 
             <img id="square" src="http://tweedfruitexchange.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/burre-pear-e1471916917953.png" /> 
           </a>
         </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid all the scripts. You don't need JS. Change the width however you like it in a separate CSS file. Below is an example of what you could do. Change size of the widths I use to fit your needs. Also, everywhere you have styling done on your html file, you need to put that on your CSS file, too. It cleans up your html & makes it easier to read.

**In CSS:**

```
#rectangle{
width: 60px;
}

#square {
width: 80px;
}
```